# JavaScript regex won't split on comma or tab space

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split text from a file that could be a csv or tab delimited. Using split function with `","` works for csv files, but when try and pass in a regex like this `"/[\s,;\t\n]+/"` bunches all the text together as one continuous string.

Is there a regex that will split the string whether the text is separated either by a comma or a tab? The files will only be either csv or tab delimited.

Comment: `"/[\s,;\t\n]+/"` is not a regular expression it's just a string. Remove the quotes, a regular expression literal is delimited by `/` only. (at least I assume that you are wrapping the regex in quotes, if not please provide a more complete example).

Comment: Do you really need a RegEx? Why not use `textVariable.split('\t')` (for tabs) and `textVariable.split(',')` for commas?

Comment: I'd say, don't reinvent the wheel, use this instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser (includes a link for using it in a browser if that would be needed)

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/[,\t]/gm` will find any comma or tab in a string. You can use it inside the split method in order to split the string. Your regex also find spaces for the `\s` and `;` and line feed for `\n` (which you don't wrote you want split on). Down here you can see an example of how I used this regex.

```js
const stringToSplit =`RegExr was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple.
    
Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over matches or the expression for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.

    The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference, and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.

Explore results with the Tools below. Replace & List output custom results. Details lists capture groups. Explain describes your expression in plain English.`

const re = /[,\t]/gm;

const splitted = stringToSplit.split(re);

console.log(splitted)
```